# Can I use stl allocators to make both an entire stl container and it's contents (keys and values) be stored inside a memory block that I created?

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl, allocator

I'm trying to understand if I can use stl allocators (http://www.drdobbs.com/the-standard-librarian-what-are-allocato/184403759) or any other C++ mechanism for my purpose.

I have a large memory block that I allocated myself.

I want to create an stl container like say map such that the container, including the keys and values stored in the container, are stored inside this memory block.

To be clear, when I say "the container, including the keys and values", I mean all the bits of memory that is would typically by allocated on the heap by the code inside the container. E.g. the graph structure, and the copies of the keys and values.

The storing of the map object itself (excluding the above-mentioned bits) in my memory block will be handled by me. Obviously I can't get something else to do that for me.

I realise that some of the replies may be "don't", but please humour me and assume that I have a good reason for wanting to store everything inside a memory block pre-allocated by me.

Comment: It would be nice to see your attempt at doing this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, yes you can do this with C++11 allocators.

Allocators are a somewhat complex topic. A good introduction to C++11 allocators can be found in Alisdair Meredith's CppCon 2014 talks [part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkiYOP3d64E) and [part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5kyiFevMJQ)

C++11 introduced [`scoped_allocator_adaptor`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/scoped_allocator_adaptor) which is an important part of making this work when you have nested STL types (e.g. something like a `map<string, vector<string>>`.

A caveat to this however: there is not a good portable way to determine in advance how big your memory block would need to be to accommodate everything you want to store inside it. To be robust and portable you would need to make a 'best guess' up front and then handle a situation where you ended up needing to allocate more memory than you reserved in your large block.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it also with C++ 2003, allocator class is not very difficult to write, below is small example I used in vs2005 and adopted to compile under clang. It counts amount of memory bytes certain usage of unordered_map requries.

ps. you say you have a block of memory from which you want your custom allocator to do allocations, to make it work you will need to have some kind of allocator which will handle frequent allocations/deallocations - for this purpose you might want to check out [Doug Lea malloc](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html) which can be configured to use such memory block.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e27368e784123954

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <limits>

int total_alloc = 0;

template <class T>
class MyAllocator {
public:
  // type definitions
  typedef T        value_type;
  typedef T*       pointer;
  typedef const T* const_pointer;
  typedef T&       reference;
  typedef const T& const_reference;
  typedef std::size_t    size_type;
  typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;

  // rebind allocator to type U
  template <class U>
  struct rebind {
    typedef MyAllocator<U> other;
  };

  // return address of values
  pointer address(reference value) const {
    return &value;
  }
  const_pointer address(const_reference value) const {
    return &value;
  }

  /* constructors and destructor
  * - nothing to do because the allocator has no state
  */
  MyAllocator() throw() {
  }
  MyAllocator(const MyAllocator&) throw() {
  }
  template <class U>
  MyAllocator(const MyAllocator<U>&) throw() {
  }
  ~MyAllocator() throw() {
  }

  // return maximum number of elements that can be allocated
  size_type max_size() const throw() {
    return (std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max)() / sizeof(T);
  }

  // allocate but don't initialize num elements of type T
  pointer allocate(size_type num, const void* = 0) {
    pointer ret = (pointer)malloc(num*sizeof(T));
    total_alloc += num*sizeof(T);
    return ret;
  }

  // initialize elements of allocated storage p with value value
  void construct(pointer p, const T& value) {
    ::new((void*)p) T(value);
  }

  // destroy elements of initialized storage p
  void destroy(pointer p) {
    // destroy objects by calling their destructor
    p->~T();
  }

  // deallocate storage p of deleted elements
  void deallocate(pointer p, size_type num) {
      total_alloc -= num*sizeof(T);
    free(p);
  }
};

/// return that all specializations of this allocator are interchangeable
template <class T1, class T2>
bool operator== (const MyAllocator<T1>&,
  const MyAllocator<T2>&) throw() {
  return true;
}
template <class T1, class T2>
bool operator!= (const MyAllocator<T1>&,
  const MyAllocator<T2>&) throw() {
  return false;
}

typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, MyAllocator<char> > stringx;

namespace std
{
template<>
struct hash<stringx> {
    size_t operator()(const stringx &str) const {
        std::hash<const char*> str_hash;
        return str_hash(str.c_str());
    }
};
}

typedef std::unordered_map<stringx, int,
  std::hash<stringx>,
  std::equal_to<stringx>,
  MyAllocator<std::pair<const stringx, std::pair<stringx, int> > > > sample_map_type;

int main()
{
  sample_map_type sample_map;
  sample_map["test1"] = 1;
  sample_map["test2"] = 2;
  for (auto elem : sample_map) {
    std::cout << elem.first << " -> " << elem.second << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << "total_alloc = " << total_alloc << std::endl;
}
```